# if elif else construct gives an error albeit working as expected

Tags: bash

I have this function:

```
function updateConfigFile()
{
    # set -x
    local CONTROLLER=$1; shift
    local IP_ADDRESS=$1; shift
    local FILE=$1; shift
    if [ $1 -eq 0 ]; then
        local FORE_STATEMENT=""
    elif [ ! -z "$1" ]; then
        local FORE_STATEMENT=$1
    else
        local FORE_STATEMENT="export"
    fi
    local NEW_RECORD="${FORE_STATEMENT} ${CONTROLLER}=${IP_ADDRESS}"
    echo $NEW_RECORD
}
```

The echo output seems to be as expected whatever I use as 4th argument, including omitting it (FORE_STATEMENT will then be the default "export" value). the problem is that if the parma is not an integer bash gives an error at the first expression of the "if" construct (but continues to process correctly the rest of the construct).

if parma4 is a string I get:[integer expression expected]

if I omit it I get -eq: unary operator expected

I understand the reason of the error, but... can I ignore it since the output seems to be always correct?

Comment: Should I used the "case... esac" construct instead?

Comment: `[ ! -z "$1" ]` what does it do?

Comment: `[ $1 -eq 0 ]` will get you that error, `unary`

Comment: No, you should not ignore it. Do you _completely_ understand the reasoning behind the error? If no, I would recommend referencing the ["Primary expressions" table from TLDP Bash Guide for Beginners](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html) and thinking about what important cases could be missed based on how your script currently works, as well as how you can refactor it for increased coverage.